# Is there any way to split flux stream?

Tags: java, spring-integration, flux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream

Im trying to analyse data in several ways (from RabbitMQ / spring cloud stream reactive).
I need to find a way to split the measurement flux into multiple "sink".
For example, I want doing ten seconds data windows, and then find the largest and smallest measurements. Or check that measurements are within safe ranges and if not - turn on the alarm (or send email).

My project:
https://github.com/Stiuil06/GreenRealTime/blob/master/grl-analysis/src/main/java/com/arturwegrzyn/grl/AnalysisApplication.java

I have tried two ways:

```
    @StreamListener
    public void receive1(@Input(AnalysisChannels.INPUT) Flux<String> measurements) {
        measurements
                .map(json -> gson.fromJson(json, Measurement.class))
                .filter(m -> m instanceof WaterLevel)
                .subscribe(m -> System.out.println(m));
    }

    @StreamListener
    public void receive2(@Input(AnalysisChannels.INPUT) Flux<String> measurements) {
        measurements
                .map(json -> gson.fromJson(json, Measurement.class))
                .filter(m -> m instanceof WaterLevel)
                .subscribe(m -> System.out.println(m));
    }
```

In this case only one listener is performed for one event (randomly onces first, onces second)

```
    @StreamListener
    public void receive2(@Input(AnalysisChannels.INPUT) Flux<String> measurements) {
        System.out.println("xyz");
        ConnectableFlux<String> publish = measurements.publish();
        publish
                .map(json -> gson.fromJson(json, Measurement.class))
                .filter(m -> m instanceof AirTemperature)
                .subscribe(m -> System.out.println(m));

        publish
                .map(json -> gson.fromJson(json, Measurement.class))
                .filter(m -> m instanceof AirTemperature)
                .subscribe(m -> System.out.println(m));
    }
```

In second case I get an exception

```
2019-09-08 16:43:12.720 ERROR 12972 --- [nalysis-group-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.dataAnalysis'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[145], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=dataAnalysis, amqp_deliveryTag=1, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=dataAnalysis.realtime-analysis-group, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_receivedRetained=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=dataAnalysis, mqtt_duplicate=false, amqp_timestamp=Sun Sep 08 16:40:49 CEST 2019, amqp_messageId=e229ef37-4672-c524-e3bb-a04e607bb9cb, id=90ff1479-e363-e13e-ead7-aa7a64aaf612, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-xcdhmSOud5ZYJquDKUgsiw, contentType=application/json, mqtt_receivedTopic=/measurement/si:mu:la:00/AirPressure, mqtt_receivedQos=1, timestamp=1567953789712}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[145], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=dataAnalysis, amqp_deliveryTag=1, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=dataAnalysis.realtime-analysis-group, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_receivedRetained=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=dataAnalysis, mqtt_duplicate=false, amqp_timestamp=Sun Sep 08 16:40:49 CEST 2019, amqp_messageId=e229ef37-4672-c524-e3bb-a04e607bb9cb, id=90ff1479-e363-e13e-ead7-aa7a64aaf612, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-xcdhmSOud5ZYJquDKUgsiw, contentType=application/json, mqtt_receivedTopic=/measurement/si:mu:la:00/AirPressure, mqtt_receivedQos=1, timestamp=1567953789712}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1200(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1542)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1468)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1451)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[145], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=dataAnalysis, amqp_deliveryTag=1, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=dataAnalysis.realtime-analysis-group, amqp_redelivered=false, mqtt_receivedRetained=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=dataAnalysis, mqtt_duplicate=false, amqp_timestamp=Sun Sep 08 16:40:49 CEST 2019, amqp_messageId=e229ef37-4672-c524-e3bb-a04e607bb9cb, id=90ff1479-e363-e13e-ead7-aa7a64aaf612, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-xcdhmSOud5ZYJquDKUgsiw, contentType=application/json, mqtt_receivedTopic=/measurement/si:mu:la:00/AirPressure, mqtt_receivedQos=1, timestamp=1567953789712}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    ... 23 more
```

How should flux/reactive stream split look like? Or maybe I should approach problem differently?

Answer (score 1):

I'm launched code shown in second case.
It was missing `connect()` there.
It should look like:

```
    public void receive2(@Input(AnalysisChannels.INPUT) Flux<String> measurements) {
        ConnectableFlux<String> publish = measurements.publish();
        publish.connect();
        publish
                .map(json -> gson.fromJson(json, Measurement.class))
                .filter(m -> m instanceof AirTemperature)
                .subscribe(m -> System.out.println(m));

        publish
                .map(json -> gson.fromJson(json, Measurement.class))
                .filter(m -> m instanceof AirTemperature)
                .subscribe(m -> System.out.println(m));
    }
```

Anyway if somebody has better solution for my logic, feel free to write it!
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, looks like this is not about splitting, but publish-subscribing, distributing the same message to several subscribers. If that is really a goal, your solution in the answer is good.

Comment: You can't have several `@StreamListener` methods on the same input trying to achieve your goal: those are going to be competing subscribers and they get messages in round-robin manner.

Comment: @ArtemBilan do you have idea how to catch this ConnectableFlux in something like bean?
I want to subscribe it from around application.
I dont want have mess in StreamListener method.

Comment: You may consider to have an `IbntegrationFlow` instead of this `@StreamListener` and use its `toReactivePublisher()` to really expose the flow as a `Publsiher<Message<?>>` bean. At this m moment you can wrap it into a `Flux` and call its `publish()` for all your those `subscribe()` everywhere else in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note:
We are going to be deprecating reactive module all together in 3.0 since the same is already handled by using spring-cloud-function programming model. Here is what your code can look like. Notice there no linger the need for EnableBinding, StreamListener and other annotations. Just `@Bean` and we'll

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Flux<String>> sink() {
    return measurements -> {
        ConnectableFlux<String> publish = measurements.publish();
        publish.connect();
        ...
    };
}
```

Here is more - https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/19/announcing-spring-cloud-stream-horsham-m3-3-0-0-m3